# Using Assembly.GetType("MyCompany.Class1.Class2") returns null

Tags: c#, .net

I'm attempting to use Assembly.GetType("MyCompany.Class1.Class2") to dynamically get a type from a string.

```
Assembly.GetType("MyCompany.Class1");
```

works as expected.

If I embed a class within another class such as:

```
namespace MyCompany
{
  public class Class1
  {
     //.....
     public class Class2
     {
        //.....
     }
  }
}
```

and try to get the type Class2

```
Assembly.GetType("MyCompany.Class1.Class2")
```

will return a null.

I'm using the .NET Frameworks 3.5 SP1

Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly and what I can do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Kevin D. Wolf
Tampa, FL

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need the Plus sign to get Nested Classes to be mapped using Assembly.GeType.

```
 Assembly.GetType("MyCompany.Class1+Class2");
```

Comment: You're close.  You need "MyCompany.Class1+Class2".

Comment: If the assembly isn't loaded in memory, you need to have the fully qualified type name. GetType("MyCompany.Class1+Class2, MyAssembly");

Comment: Assembly.GetType is an instance method, so it's safe to assume the assembly is already loaded.

Comment: what if I have the Namespace: Assembly.Folder1.Folder2.MyClass?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's named MyComnpany.Class1+Class2.

If I run this code on a similar structure, that's what I see:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type[] types = assem.GetTypes();
```

example Types to see the names.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use plus signs. Something like "MyAssembly.Class1+NestedClass".